# Dynamic javascript in ASP.Net MVC 3.0+Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a javascript that must generate in runtime.The text of script is generate in controller class :

```
private string mapString
{
    get
    {
       Locations loc = new Locations();
       string appPath = Request.ApplicationPath;
       loc.ReadXml(Path.Combine(Request.MapPath(appPath) + "\\App_Data", "Locations.xml"));
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       for (int i = 0; i < loc.Specfications.Count; i++)
       {
          sb.Append("var myLatLng" + i.ToString() + "= new google.maps.LatLng(" + loc.Specfications[i].Y.ToString() + "," +
          loc.Specfications[i].X.ToString() + ");");
          sb.Append(" var beachMarker" + i.ToString() + " = new google.maps.Marker({position: myLatLng" + i.ToString() + ",map: map,icon: image,title:'" + loc.Specfications[i].Title + "'});"); 

....

...

...

      ViewData["MapString"] = mapString;
```

When I use it in script tag :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

              function initialize() {
                 @Server.HtmlDecode(ViewData["MapString"].ToString())

              }

</script>
```

It dosen't return a true text and it retruns something like this:

**contentString0 = '<table width="100%" style="font-family: tahoma; text-align: right; font**

**update : The site didn't show my question correctly ,I want to show "'<" but it show "'<"

but it must return :
contentString0 ='
you see that it convert "'<" to "'<" .
But when I use : @Server.HtmlDecode(ViewData["MapString"].ToString()) out of script tag ,all things is OK.

Comment: First of all why would you need to generate your javascript in your controller ? As far as I can see you're passing longitude and latitude to Goole Maps API. Why not create a Controller action that would return only the data you need as JSON object ?

Comment: How can I do it?Can you give an example?Yes I want to mark on google map dyanmicaly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to do it this way, which I think is going to be more flexible than generating code in your controller :

Controller action :

```
    public JsonResult GetCoords()
    {
        // your code here - im putting a generic result you may 
        // need to put some logic here to retrieve your location / locations 

        var result = new { lon = "51.0000", lat = "23.0000" };
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

in your view add :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $.getJSON('/YourController/GetCoords', function (jsonData) {

                var lon = jsonData.lon;
                var lat = jsonData.lat;

                yourGoogleMapFunction(lon, lat);

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: The getJSON in your sample dosen'y work.I download JQery1.7.js from JQuery site but the sample didn't work.

Comment: in my controller class:                                       [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetCoords()
        {
            // your code here - im putting a generic result you may 
            // need to put some logic here to retrieve your location / locations 

            var result = new { lon = "51.0000", lat = "23.0000" };
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }

Comment: in my aspx file :      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {

             $.getJSON('HomeController/GetCoords',null, function (jsonData) {

                 var lon = jsonData.lon;
                 var lat = jsonData.lat;
                 alert('fdfd');

             });
         });
    </script>
but  the alert function didn't fire.

Comment: $.getJSON('HomeController/GetCoords',null, function (jsonData) 
I'm pretty sure that's not the way I wrote it in my sample.
Check as well if your path to controller is correct, I think you need "/" in front of your relative adress. 
For future :
Run the code in Chrome or Firefox with Firebug and launch the developer tools. Check the Network tab as you're clicking through your site to debug and trace all the errors.